# Is is possible to use TileContainer for GenericTile in sap ui5

Tags: sapui5

I have two Generic tiles and showing those tiles in two different panels.

Please check the code here - 
http://plnkr.co/edit/3k17wthvl88UmVeszWu0?p=preview

now I want to show those Tiles inside a tile container. I tried -

```
 var oContainer = new sap.m.TileContainer({});
 oContainer.addTile(Tile1);
 oContainer.addTile(Tile1);
```

this is not allowed.

is there any way I can put those generic tiles inside a tile container.

Or how put those tiles side by side in one panel.(note: when I tried one panel, Second Tile is coming below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different options if you want to stick to `sap.suite.ui.commons.GenericTile` you can use any layout like HorizontalLayout, MatrixLayout and so on

But if you want to use `sap.m.TileContainer`, you have to add tiles, which inherit from `sap.m.Tile` (as you can see here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.TileContainer/aggregations)

I forked your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gh46xYK66ii1J3O69j3q?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I want to add the Generic Tiles to the Tile container. Is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible, did you check the inheritance? As i already wrote sap.m.TileContainer has a constraint on the Tiles Aggregation. You can use CustomTile (inherits from sap.m.Tile) and customize it like you would do with the GenericTile. Or you could extend sap.m.TileContainer, but this will be more complex and takes a lot of time